# How to set an object variable dynamically via a method in Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to run a method that takes in an string and creates the object using the string as the object's variable:

```
public void createObj(String objName){
    Obj objName = new Obj();
}
```

Is this even possible? If so, how may I accomplish it?

Comment: What?  Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an expression to name a variable in Java. The closest you can get, I think, is to populate a [`Map<String, Obj>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that can be used to look up `Obj` instances by name.

```
public void createObj(String objName, Map<String, Obj> symbolTable){
    symbolTable.put(objName, new Obj());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. Declare all the local variable with different name.

A class and its members are defined and then compiled to byte code, so thse cannot be modified at dynamic at run-time.

```
public void createObj(String objName){
    Obj objectName = new Obj();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, no, this cannot be done. You can't create a named local variable at runtime.

If you want to associate names with objects, you could use a [`Map<String,Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it for a simple reason. You cannot have 2 local variables with a same name because the compiler cannot differentiate.